# What is the phenomenon of primitive values being singletons called?

Tags: javascript

From my understanding in JavaScript (And Ruby and Python) only a single instance of a given primitive value exist in memory at any given time. For example, If you instantiate a number, then that number is created in memory. Any other variable that reinstantiates that number, will actually be referencing the same number in memory that was already created. This can be illustrated with the following example:

```
var x = 5;
var y = 5;
Object.is(x, y);
>>>true
```

What is the phenomenon of primitive values being singletons called?

Comment: `From my understanding in JavaScript (And Ruby and Python) only a single instance of a given primitive value exist in memory at any given time` - Nope, not all Python's primitives are created only once in memory

Comment: You are making assumptions about specific Javascript implementations that are not in the language specification, nor relevant to how the language works (though they may influence memory usage).

Comment: Plus, your specific example only determines that `x` and `y` have the same value.  It does not mean anything about whether they are represented by the same piece of memory.  From MDN, `Object.is()` when given two numbers does this: "Two numeric values are the same if both non-zero and both not NaN and both have the same value"

Comment: Object.is tests for identity. This does in fact prove they are references to the same value in memory

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 - Not true.  Read on this page when both values are numbers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is.  When both arguments are numbers, it compares their values,

Answer (score 1):

Your test is flawed.  When both arguments to `Object.is()` are numbers, it returns a comparison of the values of the two arguments.  This is not a test for whether both variables are represented by the same physical memory.

You can read [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) for how the comparison works when both arguments are numbers.  You can also look at the polyfill on that same page.

If you want to see the actual ECMAScript specification for `Object.is()`, you can read that [here](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.is).

In that specification, `Object.is()` uses `SameValue(x,y)` which is documented as this sequence of steps:

> 19.1.2.10 Object.is ( value1, value2 )
>
> When the is function is called with arguments value1 and value2 the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> Return SameValue(value1, value2).

And here's the `SameValue()` section:

> 7.2.9 SameValue(x, y)
>
> The internal comparison abstract operation SameValue(x, y), where x and y 
>   are ECMAScript language values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is
>   performed as follows:
>
> 1. ReturnIfAbrupt(x).
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(y).
> 3. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 4. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
> 5. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
> 6. If Type(x) is Number, then
>      a. If x is NaN and y is NaN, return true.
>      b. If x is +0 and y is -0, return false.
>      c. If x is -0 and y is +0, return false.
>      d. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>      e. Return false.
> 7. If Type(x) is String, then
>      a. If x and y are exactly the same sequence of code units (same length 
>          and same code units at corresponding indices) return true;
>          otherwise, return false.
> 8. If Type(x) is Boolean, then
>       a. If x and y are both true or both false, return true; otherwise, 
>          return false.
> 9. If Type(x) is Symbol, then
>       a. If x and y are both the same Symbol value, return true; otherwise,
>          return false.
> 10. Return true if x and y are the same Object value. Otherwise, return false.

You can see that step 6 is the step that comes into play when both x and y are numbers.  Further, you can see that for strings, it is comparing to see that x and y contain the same characters, not that they are indeed the same string object.

Comment: Ruby has method object_id to see if 2 variables are actually the same in physical memory. Does JS not have something like this? Is all we have for this the identity operator? (===)

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 - as far as I know, JS does not have something that identifies the same physical memory and it's irrelevant to how the language works which is probably why it isn't offered.  For two objects, `===` will tell you if it's the same physical object (which probably has to be the same physical memory too), but other comparisons are done by comparing the value of the item, not the memory address of the item which does not tell you whether the implementation is sharing the memory storage of the item or not.

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 - I added the actual ECMAScript specification for `Object.is()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, [primitive values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) are no objects (by definition). Therefore, they do not have an [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming)), and are no singleton objects. They're just immutable values. As JavaScript is not a memory-centric language and does not allow references (pointers?) to primitive values, they cannot be distinguished.